# pygame 3.3: ImportError: DLL load failed, is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.3

So, I have python 3.3.5, and I downloaded pygame 3.3. when I type import pygame in the shell, it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pygame\__init__.py", line 127, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

What is wrong with my pygame? Is it because I am 3.3.5 and pygame is 3.3?

Comment: You can run python in verbose mode with `python -vvvv` to get more information about `ImportError`

Answer (score 0):

A few things to try:

1. Are you running 32-bit Python with 32-bit pygame? If you're running 64-bit Python, then I don't think it will work.
2. Sometimes this `ImportError` is misleading and the binary simply can't be found. Try putting the binary on your path.
3. There are unofficial Windows installers that I've found very useful in the past at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame. They also have a pygame build. Try installing pygame from there. You may need to uninstall pygame first.